# Bitmask helper and operator overloading syntax design

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am writing a small helper class to assist with setting bitflags based on a bitmask. But I am having some trouble designing a good and clear syntax using operator overloading. To illustrate, some possible ideas looks something like the following (`bit` namespace and 'mask' class are mine):

```
unsigned int flags = 0x01011001;
unsigned int mask  = 0x00001001;
const bool updateVal = getNewValFromElsewhere();
```

1) (using a `reference` to flags and updating accordingly)

```
flags & bit::mask(mask) = updateVal ; //i sort of like this one
bit::mask(mask) & flags = updateVal ; //but what is this supposed to mean then ?
```

or

2) could also be pass by value instead of reference

```
flags = flags & mask = updateVal ; //looks cryptic to me
flags &= mask = updateVal; //still somewhat cryptic
```

As you can see, it just doesn't feel intuitive and concise. I need help with designing the syntax, not with actual implemenation (but within the limits of c++).
The `operator&` used with flags is not my biggest concern and can be changed to whatever operator to initiate the custom behavior, but will that help alot ? Should I drop the whole idea of operator overloading for this helper class ? (why?)

3) Example without operator overloading

```
bit::mask_flags(flags, mask).set(updateVal);//doesn't feel so good
bit::bitflags(flags).set_using_mask(mask, updateVal)//maybe better, but then what with other operations than setting..
```

Comment: as some even consider operator overloading a bad idea in general, I think this quesiton is opinion based. Actually I would expect `&` to return a new value, not a reference to the lhs

Comment: well, `std` has the `std::bitset` (with a lot of operator overloads i might add). It comes close to what i would like to do but doesn't support masked operations for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I ended up somewhere in between and I think it provides enough 'syntax' while also support flexible building blocks and avoiding the pitfalls of a bare function.

```
bit::flags_ref( flags ).with_mask( mask ) = updateVal;
```